# Binary Image "Lines-of-Sight" Edge Detection

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, edge-detection

Consider this binary image:
[image]

A normal edge detection algorithm (Like [Canny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector)) takes the binary image as input and results into the contour shown in red. I need another algorithm that takes a point "P" as a second piece of input data. "P" is the black point in the previous image. This algorithm should result into the blue contour. The blue contours represents the point "P" lines-of-sight edge of the binary image.

I searched a lot of an image processing algorithm that achieve this, but didn't find any. I also tried to think about a new one, but I still have a lot of difficulties.

Comment: How are your contours represented? Are they polygons or bitmaps?

Comment: @Kaganar They are Bitmaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've got a bitmap, you could use a bitmap algorithm.

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/zjooqfqt/26/) (in JSFiddle or see below). (Firefox, Chrome, but not IE)

Pseudocode:

```
// part 1: occlusion
mark all pixels as 'outside'
for each pixel on the edge of the image
    draw a line from the source pixel to the edge pixel and
    for each pixel on the line starting from the source and ending with the edge
        if the pixel is gray mark it as 'inside'
        otherwise stop drawing this line

// part 2: edge finding
for each pixel in the image
    if pixel is not marked 'inside' skip this pixel
    if pixel has a neighbor that is outside mark this pixel 'edge'

// part 3: draw the edges
highlight all the edges
```

At first this sounds pretty terrible... But really, it's `O(p)` where `p` is the number of pixels in your image.

Full code here, works best full page:

```js
var c = document.getElementById('c');
c.width = c.height = 500;
var x = c.getContext("2d");

//////////// Draw some "interesting" stuff ////////////
function DrawScene() {
    x.beginPath();
    x.rect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    x.fillStyle = '#fff';
    x.fill();

    x.beginPath();
    x.rect(c.width * 0.1, c.height * 0.1, c.width * 0.8, c.height * 0.8);
    x.fillStyle = '#000';
    x.fill();
    
    x.beginPath();
    x.rect(c.width * 0.25, c.height * 0.02 , c.width * 0.5, c.height * 0.05);
    x.fillStyle = '#000';
    x.fill();

    x.beginPath();
    x.rect(c.width * 0.3, c.height * 0.2, c.width * 0.03, c.height * 0.4);
    x.fillStyle = '#fff';
    x.fill();

    x.beginPath();
    var maxAng = 2.0;
    function sc(t) { return t * 0.3 + 0.5; }
    function sc2(t) { return t * 0.35 + 0.5; }
    for (var i = 0; i < maxAng; i += 0.1)
        x.lineTo(sc(Math.cos(i)) * c.width, sc(Math.sin(i)) * c.height);
    for (var i = maxAng; i >= 0; i -= 0.1)
        x.lineTo(sc2(Math.cos(i)) * c.width, sc2(Math.sin(i)) * c.height);
    x.closePath();
    x.fill();

    x.beginPath();
    x.moveTo(0.2 * c.width, 0.03 * c.height);
    x.lineTo(c.width * 0.9, c.height * 0.8);
    x.lineTo(c.width * 0.8, c.height * 0.8);
    x.lineTo(c.width * 0.1, 0.03 * c.height);
    x.closePath();
    x.fillStyle = '#000';
    x.fill();
}

//////////// Pick a point to start our operations: ////////////
var v_x = Math.round(c.width * 0.5);
var v_y = Math.round(c.height * 0.5);

function Update() {
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'
        ||  !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/rv 11/))
        || $.browser.msie == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = "Does not work in IE.";
        return;
    }
    
    DrawScene();

    //////////// Make our image binary (white and gray) ////////////
    var id = x.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < id.width * id.height * 4; i += 4) {
        id.data[i + 0] = id.data[i + 0] > 128 ? 255 : 64;
        id.data[i + 1] = id.data[i + 1] > 128 ? 255 : 64;
        id.data[i + 2] = id.data[i + 2] > 128 ? 255 : 64;
    }

    // Adapted from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Bresenham's_line_algorithm#JavaScript
    function line(x1, y1) {
        var x0 = v_x;
        var y0 = v_y;
        var dx = Math.abs(x1 - x0), sx = x0 < x1 ? 1 : -1;
        var dy = Math.abs(y1 - y0), sy = y0 < y1 ? 1 : -1; 
        var err = (dx>dy ? dx : -dy)/2;

        while (true) {
            var d = (y0 * c.height + x0) * 4;
            if (id.data[d] === 255) break;
            id.data[d] = 128;
            id.data[d + 1] = 128;
            id.data[d + 2] = 128;

            if (x0 === x1 && y0 === y1) break;
            var e2 = err;
            if (e2 > -dx) { err -= dy; x0 += sx; }
            if (e2 < dy) { err += dx; y0 += sy; }
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < c.width; i++) line(i, 0);
    for (var i = 0; i < c.width; i++) line(i, c.height - 1);
    for (var i = 0; i < c.height; i++) line(0, i);
    for (var i = 0; i < c.height; i++) line(c.width - 1, i);
    
    // Outline-finding algorithm
    function gb(x, y) {
        var v = id.data[(y * id.height + x) * 4];
        return v !== 128 && v !== 0;
    }
    for (var y = 0; y < id.height; y++) {
        var py = Math.max(y - 1, 0);
        var ny = Math.min(y + 1, id.height - 1);
                    console.log(y);

        for (var z = 0; z < id.width; z++) {
            var d = (y * id.height + z) * 4;
            if (id.data[d] !== 128) continue;
            var pz = Math.max(z - 1, 0);
            var nz = Math.min(z + 1, id.width - 1);
            if (gb(pz, py) || gb(z, py) || gb(nz, py) ||
                gb(pz, y) || gb(z, y) || gb(nz, y) ||
                gb(pz, ny) || gb(z, ny) || gb(nz, ny)) {
                id.data[d + 0] = 0;
                id.data[d + 1] = 0;
                id.data[d + 2] = 255;
            }
        }
    }

    x.putImageData(id, 0, 0);

    // Draw the starting point
    x.beginPath();
    x.arc(v_x, v_y, c.width * 0.01, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    x.fillStyle = '#800';
    x.fill();
}

Update();

c.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    var x = evt.pageX - c.offsetLeft,
        y = evt.pageY - c.offsetTop;
    v_x = x;
    v_y = y;
    Update();
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center><div id="d">Click on image to change point</div>
<canvas id="c"></canvas></center>
```

Comment: If you're looking to result in a vector representation of the outline, you could just connect the line hits -- you'd end up with something very similar to what @LouisRicci suggests, but it'd have better behavior than a constant-angle radial sweep.

Answer (score 2):

I would just estimate P's line of sight contour with ray collisions.

```
RESOLUTION = PI / 720;
For rad = 0 To PI * 2 Step RESOLUTION
  ray = CreateRay(P, rad)
  hits = Intersect(ray, contours)
  If Len(hits) > 0
    Add(hits[0], lineOfSightContour)
```

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_surface_determination with e.g. a Z-Buffer is relatively easy. Edge detection looks a lot trickier and probably needs a bit of tuning. Why not take an existing edge detection algorithm from a library that somebody else has tuned, and then stick in some Z-buffering code to compute the blue contour from the red?

Answer (score 1):

**First approach**

*Main idea*

1. Run an edge detection algorithm (Canny should do it just fine).
2. For each contour point `C` compute the triplet `(slope, dir, dist)`, where:

   - `slope` is the slope of the line that passes through `P` and `C`
   - `dir` is a bit which is set if `C` is to the right of `P` (on the `x` axis) and reset if it is to the left; it used in order to distinguish in between points having the same slope, but on opposite sides of `P`
   - `dist` is the distance in between `P` and `C`.
3. Classify the set of contour points such that a class contains the points with the same key `(slope, dir)` and keep the one point from each such class having the minimum `dist`. Let `S` be the set of these closest points.
4. Sort `S` in clockwise order.
5. Iterate once more through the sorted set and, whenever two consecutive points are too far apart, draw a segment in between them, otherwise just draw the points.

*Notes*

- You do not really need to compute the real distance in between `P` and `C` since you only use `dist` to determine the closest point to `P` at step 3. Instead you can keep `C.x - P.x` in `dist`. This piece of information should also tell you which of two points with the same slope is closest to `P`. Also, `C.x - P.x` swallows the `dir` parameter (in the sign bit). So you do not really need `dir` either.
- The classification in step 3 can ideally be done by hashing (thus, in linear number of steps), but since doubles/floats are subject to rounding, you might need to allow small errors to occur by rounding the values of the slopes.

**Second approach**

*Main idea*

You can perform a sort of BFS starting from `P`, like when trying to determine the country/zone that `P` resides in. For each pixel, look at the pixels around it that were already visited by BFS (called neighbors). Depending on the distribution of the neighbor pixels that are in the line of sight, determine if the currently visited pixel is in the line of sight too or not. You can probably apply a sort of convolution operator on the neighbor pixels (like with any other filter). Also, you do not really need to decide right away if a pixel is for sure in the line of sight. You could instead compute some probability of that to be true.

*Notes*

- Due to the fact that your graph is a 2D image, BFS should be pretty fast (since the number of edges is linear in the number of vertices).
- This second approach eliminates the need to run an edge detection algorithm. Also, if the country/zone `P` resides in is considerably smaller than the image the overall performance should be better than running an edge detection algorithm solely.